# Grid parallax (like apple on High Sierra page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am trying to make a simple parallax effect within a two sided grid.
On Apple's site they use on the High Sierra page an parallax effect. ( https://www.apple.com/nl/macos/high-sierra-preview/ )

[Here is a picture of the section with the parallax effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as3Bb.png)

The right half of the grid is moving slower then the left side of the grid.

I have tried to achieve this effect, but I come up to several problems:

- Parallax Scrolling infinity: Apple's effect stops at a certain point.
- Alignment of the components in the grid.

Can anybody help me?

This is what I have tried...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e){
        parallax();
    });
    function parallax(){
        var scrolledVertical = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.vertical').css('top','+' + ((scrolledVertical/1.3)) + 'px');
    }
    });
```

Comment: You need to at least try writing some code first and then showing it here if there are problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling to find out a tutorial to achieve this exact effect. But I don't find anything...